# erlang rpc call to static member function of c# class using NFX

Tags: c#, erlang

I'm trying to call c# static member function from erlang using nfx. I follow doc http://blog.aumcode.com/2013/10/nfx-native-interoperability-of-net-with.html and I am able to call erlang:now from C# and System.DateTime.UtcNow from erlang. However when I try to call non-System from erlang, I get error

** exception error: no match of right hand side value {error,
                                                       "unknown type: 'Program'"}

C# code:

```
namespace erlangIntegration {
public class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var n = new ErlLocalNode("abc", new ErlAtom("'asdf'"));
        n.AcceptConnections = false;
        n.Start();

        var m = n.CreateMbox("test");
        var r = m.RPC("r@myPC", "erlang", "now", new ErlList());

        Console.WriteLine("Remote time: {0}", r.ValueAsDateTime.ToString());

        System.Console.WriteLine("My simple rpc: " + Program.FixedDate());
        System.Console.WriteLine("Done. Press any key to exit.");
        System.Console.ReadKey();
    }
    public static DateTime FixedDate() {
        return new DateTime(2000, 12, 12);
    }
}
```

}

erlang calls:

```
(r@myPC)2> f(Time), {ok, Time} = rpc:call('abc@myPC', 'System.DateTime', 'UtcNow', []), calendar:now_to_local_time(Time).
```

Above call works returning {{2016,1,18},{11,33,17}}
However

```
(r@myPC)12> f(Time), {ok, Time} = rpc:call('abc@myPC', 'Program', 'FixedDate', []), calendar:now_to_local_time(Time).
```

returns error:
** exception error: no match of right hand side value {error,
                                                       "unknown type: 'Program'"}

I also tried erlangIntegration.Program and to use System namespace.
How to properly make rpc call to c#?

Answer (score 0):

Erlang requires assembly qualified name as input in rpc:call. So instead of 'Program' output of the following code has to be used:

```
var obj = new Program();
//type from here has to be used in Erlang's call instead of 'Program'
System.Console.WriteLine("Type: " + obj.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName);
```